# Update iMovie in OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, software-update, imovie

My iMac is running OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard).  I still have iMovie 7.1.4. How do I update it? And which version of iMovie is it compatible with OS X 10.6.8?

Comment: I wouldn't do anything until you have fixed your other issue at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199453/imovies-error-50

Answer (score 1):

You can get the iMovie 8.0.6 from Apple website

https://support.apple.com/kb/dl859?locale=en_US

You can also buy it on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XKRZES), the "iLife 11" package that contains iMovie 09 version.