# IMovie error -50

Tags: imovie

I am working in IMovie 7.1.4. When I try to export the movie I get this error message...
"The project could not be prepared for publishing because an error occurred. (Error code = -50)"

Answer (score 2):

Error code = -50 would usually suggest a write error - whether permissions or an actual disk error I'm finding it hard to ascertain.

I would start by checking & fixing Permissions & Verify & if necessary Repair Disk from Disk Utility.